# If-else condition in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's a [link](https://regex101.com/r/rHpPY0/1/) to a regex. I want to do something like:

```
if STATE is FIXED:
   do a
else:
   do b
```

with the regex and I wrote a regex

```
(?(?=.*?"state":"FIXED")"a":"(.*?)"|"b":"(.*?)")
```

It is working with php but not with javascript regex engine. Giving the following error.

```
? The preceding token is not quantifiable
```

I want to know why this is happening and what will be the correct regex for javascript engine.

Comment: Seems XY Question? Can you share your exact problem

Comment: Conditional regexes are not supported by JavaScript regex engine.